# Repository creating a method that return a dictionary with SQL table columns

Tags: c#, sql, generics, dictionary, repository

I need to make a method in my repository that creates a dictionary with two strings that would be representing columns with nvarchar.. I'm using EF, and SQL-server as DB.

I am having a hard time grasping the concept of how the method would look like with the right args and how to return the method.

I know how to populate it from the DB, that's about it.

Comment: If you're creating a dictionary for 2 columns. You are basically just linking the 2 objects and I believe you would need to have a join using tables and not columns

Comment: Also for more on this see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ef+dictionary

Comment: Thank you for the link, havent seen that before! well am creating a dictionary for one tables two columns, both nvarchar. Thanks for your answer, back to research i guess! :)